# How do I write a constant-space length function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

The canonical implementation of `length :: [a] -> Int` is:

```
length [] = 0
length (x:xs) = 1 + length xs
```

which is very beautiful but suffers from stack overflow as it uses linear space.

The tail-recursive version:

```
length xs = length' xs 0
  where length' [] n = n
        length' (x:xs) n = length xs (n + 1)
```

doesn't suffer from this problem, but I don't understand how this can run in constant space in a lazy language.

Isn't the runtime accumulating numerous `(n + 1)` thunks as it moves through the list?  Shouldn't this function Haskell to consume O(n) space and lead to stack overflow?

(if it matters, I'm using GHC)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you've run into a common pitfall with accumulating parameters.  The usual cure is to force strict evaluation on the accumulating parameter; for this purpose I like the strict application operator `$!`.  If you don't force strictness, GHC's optimizer might decide it's OK for this function to be strict, but it might not.  Definitely it's not a thing to rely on—sometimes you *want* an accumulating parameter to be evaluated lazily and O(N) space is just fine, thank you.

> How do I write a constant-space length function in Haskell?

As noted above, use the strict application operator to force evaluation of the accumulating parameter:

```
clength xs = length' xs 0
  where length' []     n = n
        length' (x:xs) n = length' xs $! (n + 1)
```

The type of `$!` is `(a -> b) -> a -> b`, and it forces the evaluation of the `a` before applying the function.

Answer (score 12):

Running your second version in GHCi:

```
> length [1..1000000]
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

So to answer your question: Yes, it does suffer from that problem, just as you expect.

However, GHC is smarter than the average compiler; if you compile with optimizations turned out, it'll fix the code for you and make it work in constant space.

More generally, there are ways to force *strictness* at specific points in Haskell code, preventing the building of deeply nested thunks. A usual example is `foldl` vs. `foldl'`:

```
len1 = foldl (\x _ -> x + 1) 0
len2 = foldl' (\x _ -> x + 1) 0
```

Both functions are left folds that do the "same" thing, except that `foldl` is lazy while `foldl'` is strict. The result is that `len1` dies with a stack overflow in GHCi, while `len2` works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A tail-recursive function doesn't need to maintain a stack, since the value returned by the function is simply going to be the value returned by the tail call. So instead of creating a new stack frame, the current one gets re-used, with the locals overwritten by the new values passed into the tail call. So every `n+1` gets written into the same place where the old `n` was, and you have constant space usage.

Edit - Actually, as you've written it, you're right, it'll thunk the `(n+1)`s and cause an overflow. Easy to test, just try `length [1..1000000]`.. You can fix that by forcing it to evaluate it first: `length xs $! (n+1)`, which will then work as I said above.

Comment: The questioner's code does indeed overflow the stack. Generally speaking, in Haskell tail recursion does **not** do what you expect it to do, and lazy tail-recursive functions are often bugs. See here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl' Rule of thumb: either make it strict like `foldl'`, or make it recurse into a constructor like `foldr`.

Comment: Aw, nuts. Markdown doesn't like apostrophes at the end of a URL, apparently. Let's try that again: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27