# Haskell Writing myLength

Tags: haskell

I was working on this page

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/Solutions/4

I understand what each function means and it is fun to see that a function can be defined in numerous ways like this. However, I just started wondering which one is faster. And I thought it would be the one it says is `length` in `Prelude`.

```
length [] = 0
length (x:xs) = 1 + length xs
```

However, this is much slower than `length` in `Prelude`.

On my computer `length` in `Prelude` returns a length of `[1..10^7]` in 0.37 sec. However the function defined as above took 15.26 sec.

I defined my own length function, which makes use of an accumulator. It took only 8.99 sec.

I am wondering why these big differences occurred?

Comment: Did you mean `length (x:xs) = 1 + length xs` in the second line of your definition?

Comment: The answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777686/how-do-i-write-a-constant-space-length-function-in-haskell) might also be helpful.

Comment: @chris Yea I am sorry. i'll fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say "`length` in `Prelude` returns ... in 0.37 sec", which compiler are you referring to? If you are using GHC, you can see, e.g., [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-List.html#length) that the actual implementation differs from the simple

```
length [] = 0
length (x:xs) = 1 + length xs
```

Namely, it is:

```
length l = len l 0#
  where
    len :: [a] -> Int# -> Int
    len []     a# = I# a#
    len (_:xs) a# = len xs (a# +# 1#)
```

This code uses an accumulator and avoids the problem of huge unevaluated thunks by using unboxed integers, i.e., this version is highly optimized.

To illustrate the problem with the "simple" version, consider how `length [1, 2, 3]` is evaluated:

```
length [1, 2, 3]
  => 1 + length [2, 3]
  => 1 + (1 + length [3])
  => 1 + (1 + (1 + length []))
  => 1 + (1 + (1 + 0))
```

The sum is not evaluated until its result is really needed, thus you see that when the input is a huge list, you will create a huge sum in memory first and then only evaluate it when its result is really needed.

In contrast the optimized version evaluates as follows:

```
length [1, 2, 3]
  => len [1, 2, 3] 0#
  => len [2, 3] (1#)
  => len [3] (2#)
  => len [] (3#)
  => 3
```

i.e., the "+1" is done immediately.

Comment: Note that GHC is able to unbox things itself -- it's not really necessary for you to write the unboxed version, at least with modern GHC. In particular, `length = len 0 where { len :: Int -> [a] -> Int; len a [] = a; len a (_:xs) = len (a + 1) xs }` compiles to pretty much the same Core (if you eta-expand it to be more like the other definition, it seems to compile to slightly worse Core :-( But it's only a constant cost per list -- you wouldn't see any significant difference). The big difference is the accumulator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was using GHCi. Hmm... It seems that there are a lot of things beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

Two steps that you should watch out for are:

- Are you running the code compiled and not in ghci?
- Are you using the -O2 flag

The following benchmarks were done in criterion and use the following functions along with [prelude's length](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#length) which requires the `MagicHash` pragma and importing `GHC.Base`:

```
myLength1 :: [a] -> Int                                                          
myLength1 [] = 0                                                                 
myLength1 (x:xs) = 1 + myLength1 xs                                              

myLength2 :: [a] -> Int                                                          
myLength2 lst = len lst 0                                                        
  where                                                                          
    len :: [a] -> Int -> Int                                                     
    len [] n = n                                                                 
    len (_:xs) n = len xs (n+1)                                                  

myLength3                  :: [a] -> Int                                         
myLength3 l                =  len l 0#                                           
  where                                                                          
    len :: [a] -> Int# -> Int                                                    
    len []     a# = I# a#                                                        
    len (_:xs) a# = len xs (a# +# 1#)
```

The results of the benchmark, found in full at the end, with out using teh `-O2` flag are:

```
              mean
length    :   5.4818 ms
myLength1 : 202.1552 ms
myLength2 : 236.3042 ms
myLength3 :   5.3630 ms
```

Now lets use the `-02` flag when compiling

```
              mean
length    :   5.2597 ms
myLength1 :   12.882 ms
myLength2 :   5.2026 ms
myLength3 :   5.6393 ms,
```

Notice that length the `myLength3` do not change but the remaining two change considerably.  The naive approach is inside a factor of 3 different and `myLength2` is now comparible with the built in length by mimics the prelude length in all but using  unboxing.

Also note worthy is that myLength3 which unboxes the Int does not change much and would probably preform much better in ghci then myLength 1 or 2.

Full code at: https://gist.github.com/Davorak/5457105

Edit: Some further information that would not fit in a comment:

The ghc flag `-O2` with the letter means “Apply every non-dangerous optimisation, even if it means significantly longer compile times." I would not be surprised if this involves some unboxing of datatypes.  You can find further explanations of different flags [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/options-optimise.html).  Here is a [linke](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html) with a larger list of flags for ghc 7.6.2 the explanations can be short and cryptic however.

I am not intimately familiar with unboxing and primitive operations and their consequences here is a third [link to the GHC manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/primitives.html) that covers unboxed types. You will occasionally find them mention in optimization tutorials.  Most of the time you should not bother with them unless you really need every gram of performance since as we say above they often will only make a constant difference after other optimization flags are used.

Comment: The effect of using an unboxed accumulator is that the compiler _cannot_ produce inefficient code from that, even without optimisations. With `myLength2`, you need the strictness analyser to unbox the accumulator, but with that, you get identical code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am actually a beginner, and so far I have only used GHCi... and never heard of 02. Is O2 related to Int#? I have never seen Int# before...

Comment: @Tengu I edited my answer since the reply did not fit well into a comment and others might benefit as well.

Comment: @Davorak Thank you very much for your answer. I really appreciate it and read it a few times, but it seems too difficult for me. I will read your answer one I have more knowledge in this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Tengu I would appreciate hearing what were the hard parts to understand so next time I make an explanation it can be a little better, if you have a moment to write it down for me.

Comment: @Davorak I do not believe that this is because of your explanation. Actually your explanation seems to be very helpful, containing several examples, but it is just the amount of knowledge I have is so poor. I am reading "Learn You a Haskell for great good" and I am just done with recursion.

Comment: @Tengu Ok, hopefully it will click together as you are learning more then and I hope I see you around.

Answer (score 0):

The prelude is specification of semantics only; it doesn't constrain the implementation. 
From http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#x16-1710009:

> It constitutes a specification for the Prelude. Many of the definitions are written with clarity rather than efficiency in mind, and it is not required that the specification be implemented as shown here.

In the case of GHC, the actual `length` function is highly optimized.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that this is beyond my ability, so I will not think too much about it... I will definitely come back here when I am more familiar with Haskell. Thanks anyway!